# Unable to remove the Search Service Appln Pool from the service accounts Page in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, service-account, searchserviceapplication

In order to remove a search service application, i have tried to remove the search content dbs using powershell mentioned here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/66f664b5-1586-4290-beb3-a7acfe739fb7/unable-to-delete-search-service-application-operand-type-clash?forum=sharepointadminprevious
and I got the removal of contentd dbs related with search.
But when i went to central admin -->service accounts --> selected the dropdown credential mgmnt-> that service application pool for that unwanted service application pool was still showing up!
how to remove that item from the dropdown?

why this applicqation pool is not shown in INETMGR ?
here is the scrn shot:
[image: SERVICE-APPLN-ACCOUNT-REMOVAL]

when i tried to delete the spmanaged account :

> An object in the SharePoint administrative framework, "SPManagedAccount Name=managed-account-S-1-5-21-266749940-1637964444-929701000-1532211", could not be deleted because other objects depend on it.  Update all of these dependants to point to null or different objects and retry this operation.  The dependant objects are as follows: 
>   SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool Name=SearchPool 
>   SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool Name=UserProfilePool 
>   SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool Name=UserProfileServiceAppPool

how can i **Update all of these dependants to point to null** ? can i do this using powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Managed account details are stored in the Configuration Database.

You can use below powershell to remove

```
Remove-SPManagedAccount -Identity DOMAIN\ServiceAcct
```

Comment: am getting an error while trying to run the command :Remove-SPManagedAccount : The account domain\user1 is still being u
sed by these components:
XLservice
Security Token Service Application
Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application.
At line:1 char:24
+ Remove-SPManagedAccount <<<<  -Identity domain\user1
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: Microsoft.Share...eManagedAccount:
   SPCmdletRemoveManagedAccount) [Remove-SPManagedAccount], InvalidOperationE
  xception     + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRemoveMa
   nagedAccount

Comment: Validate the service account is not being used in XLService, STS etc.

Comment: am getting th other error : An object in the SharePoint administrative framework, "SPManagedAccount Name=managed-account-S-1-5-21-266749940-1637964444-929701000-1532211", could not be deleted because other objects depend on it.  Update all of these dependants to point to null or different objects and retry this operation.  The dependant objects are as follows: 
SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool Name=SearchPool 
SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool Name=UserProfilePool 
SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool Name=UserProfileServiceAppPool

Comment: one more link i saw :https://kjaerulff.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/spmanagedaccount-could-not-be-deleted-because-other-objects-depend-on-it/